# Python ctypes: how to use pointer passed to DLL?

Tags: python, ctypes

Using ctypes, I create an array in Python to pass to a ctypes.WinDLL:

```
arrA = (ctypes.c_float * len(varA))(*varA)
```

Then I pass a pointer to the array into the DLL:

```
retvar = SimpleTest(ctypes.byref(pvarr),ctypes.byref(pvarr2))
```

Where the first element of *pvarr* is a pointer to the array *arrA*.

But when I try to write to values to the array *arrA* (using the pointer that was passed), I get "invalid access to memory location."

So my question is:  how can I now use the pointer to a ctypes.c_float array created in Python and passed to a DLL?  Is that not possible?

---

After working on this for awhile, I have refined the problem.  The array shown above is  immutable; to pass a mutable array, we do this:

```
OutputArrayType = ctypes.c_float * 1000
arrNew = OutputArrayType()
```

The ctypes array type is a  class, so to use it we must create a class instance (arrayNew).

But when I pass its pointer by reference:

```
retvar = SimpleTest(ctypes.byref(PVarrNew),ctypes.byref(arrNew))
```

the pointer value is a different number from id(arrayNew).  Even so, the DLL still cannot access any values in either pointer, as I get "invalid access to memory."

So my question now is:  why does the pointer passed by ctypes.byref(arrNew) differ from id(arrNew).

---

Mark, thanks for your reply.  Here is the concise summary:

The first array is not mutable in place, it creates a new object with each assignment; I confirmed that by checking its id() before and after an assignment.  However, the second array, instantiated as a class, is mutable in place so that's why I use it.

So I create the array:

```
OutputArrayType = ctypes.c_int64 * 1000
arrNew = OutputArrayType()
```

and call the DLL:

```
retvar = SimpleTest(ctypes.byref(PVarrNew),ctypes.byref(arrNew))
```

In 64-bit assembler, the second parameter (the pointer to *arrNew*) is passed in rdx.  So in NASM, I can write to this array in two different ways, but both return "invalid access to memory location."

```
mov rdi,rdx
mov rax,1534
mov [rdi+8],rax
```

```
push qword [rax]
pop qword [rdx+32]
```

If I reverse the order of the arrays in the call to the DLL (where the pointer to the array is in rcx), the same happens.

However, I can *read* from the array, but I can't write to it.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Your original attempt is mutable, not immutable, so both of your examples are the same.  The id() of an object in CPython's case is the address of the Python object that wraps the array, not the address of the array itself, so that is why they differ.  Create a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the issue ourselves.

Comment: Mark -- please see additional information above.  Thanks.

Comment: What is `pvarr`?  What is `pvarr2`? Show a reproducible example.  Read the [mcve] guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are both mutable.  You mentioned an *assignment*, that always creates a new object but without an example... :^)  Here's what I mean about a reproducible example.  Works compiled 32- or 64-bit using appropriate Python:

**test.c** (Windows example with Microsoft compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SimpleTest(float* array, int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = %f\n",i,array[i]);
        array[i] *= 2;
    }
}
```

**test.py** (portable between Python 2 and 3)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ctypes import *
varA = [1.2,2.5,3.5]
arr = (c_float * len(varA))(*varA)  # 1st example
print(id(arr))
arr[0] = 1.5 # mutate array
print(id(arr))

arrType = c_float * 10    # 2nd example
arrInstance = arrType()
print(id(arrInstance))
arrInstance[0] = 1.5 # mutate array
print(id(arrInstance))

dll = WinDLL('test')
print(list(arr))
dll.SimpleTest(arr,len(arr)) # Passing the array to C and changing it
print(list(arr))
```

**Output** (same on 32-and 64- except the IDs are different, note the ID doesn't change after mutation)

```
2610964912456
2610964912456
2610964912968
2610964912968
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
array[0] = 1.500000
array[1] = 2.500000
array[2] = 3.500000
[3.0, 5.0, 7.0]
```